# cannot git add.gitignore

Tags: git

I  inputted the following:

```
mkdir project_name
cd project_name
git init
touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
```

I got the following response:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.gitignore
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

I couldn't find any gitignore files that could cause this.  Is there a recommended way to find out what is causing the issue?

Comment: can you check 'git log .gitignore' or 'git status' see what's in your repository ? If this is a subfolder, I would suggest running a 'find . -name .gitignore' from the top level and double-checking them...

Comment: i ran git status but git is empty.  also i created this in my home directory.  ran find . -name in toplevel but still can't find anything...so u are saying it has to be a parent directory .gitignore causing this? thx

Comment: ok ...thx...i found a gitignore_global file...don't know where that came from...thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the file is ignored in the [global ignore definition](http://help.github.com/git-ignore/).

Search for the `~/.gitignore_global` file and remove the line with `.gitignore`.